# Stata interaction variable base year

Tags: variables, stata, interaction

My data is in the following format:

```
clear all
input year  ID  var1    var2
2000    1   100 .
2001    1   200 0.2
2002    1   300 0.3
2000    2   500 .
2001    2   300 0.4
2002    2   400 0.1
end
```

I would like to create an interaction variable between `var1` and `var2` where `var1` always takes the value of the first year where I have data (in this case `year` 2000 as the base year).

| year | ID | var1 | var2 | var1xvar2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 100 | . | . |
| 2001 | 1 | 200 | 0.2 | 20 |
| 2002 | 1 | 300 | 0.3 | 30 |
| 2000 | 2 | 500 | . | . |
| 2001 | 2 | 300 | 0.4 | 200 |
| 2002 | 2 | 400 | 0.1 | 50 |

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
bysort ID (year): gen wanted = var1[1] * var2

list, sepby(ID)

     +----------------------------------+
     | year   ID   var1   var2   wanted |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. | 2000    1    100      .        . |
  2. | 2001    1    200     .2       20 |
  3. | 2002    1    300     .3       30 |
     |----------------------------------|
  4. | 2000    2    500      .        . |
  5. | 2001    2    300     .4      200 |
  6. | 2002    2    400     .1       50 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

The [1] refers to the first observation in each ID panel, which in this case is the lowest value of year because the dataset is sorted by ID and year.